# Remove <a> tags via PHP & keep content of tag?

Tags: php, tags, string-matching

Is it possible to remove all `<a>` tags / links from strings while keeping the content? `strip_tags` is not an option, because there are `<p>` tags in it which I want to keep. The links are structured this way:

```
<a style="color: #000000" href="{url}">***content***</a>
```

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

The strip_tags method accepts a second optional parameter with tags not to remove.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Exemple from Php.net:

```
<?php $text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a ref="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";
// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
The above example will output:
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```